# Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE be specified when creating a PendingIntent

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging

Error

```
Exception java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: se.sensoralarm: Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE be specified when creating a PendingIntent.
Strongly consider using FLAG_IMMUTABLE, only use FLAG_MUTABLE if some functionality depends on the PendingIntent being mutable, e.g. if it needs to be used with inline replies or bubbles.
  at android.app.PendingIntent.checkFlags (PendingIntent.java:408)
  at android.app.PendingIntent.getActivityAsUser (PendingIntent.java:491)
  at android.app.PendingIntent.getActivity (PendingIntent.java:477)
  at android.app.PendingIntent.getActivity (PendingIntent.java:441)
  at com.google.firebase.messaging.zza.zzh
  at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService.zzd
  at com.google.firebase.iid.zzg.run
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1137)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:637)
  at com.google.android.gms.common.util.concurrent.zza.run (com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@18.1.0:2)
  at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:1012)
```

My method to show notification

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,
        0, new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SplashScreenActivity.class), PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE|PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification)
        .setContentTitle(title)
        .setContentText(messageBody)
        .setAutoCancel(true)
        .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

NotificationManager notificationManager =
        (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
```

build.gradel config

```
compileSdkVersion 32
buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "se.sensoralarm"
    minSdkVersion 23
    targetSdkVersion 32
    versionCode 32
    versionName "1.2.12"
    testInstrumentationRunner 'androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner'
}
```

Dependence

```
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.play:core:1.10.2'
testImplementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestImplementation('androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
implementation 'androidx.work:work-runtime:2.8.1'
implementation 'androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:2.8.1'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
implementation 'androidx.exifinterface:exifinterface:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.9.0'
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
implementation 'com.aurelhubert:ahbottomnavigation:2.1.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
implementation 'com.github.chrisbanes:PhotoView:2.1.3'
implementation 'com.jakewharton.threetenabp:threetenabp:1.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:21.1.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4'
implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:10.2.3'
implementation 'org.florescu.android.rangeseekbar:rangeseekbar-library:0.3.0'
implementation 'com.github.lukedeighton:wheelview:0.4.2'
implementation 'org.florescu.android.rangeseekbar:rangeseekbar-library:0.3.0'
implementation 'com.intuit.ssp:ssp-android:1.0.6'
implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.6'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:18.3.7'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:21.2.0'
implementation("com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:18.1.0")
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:10.2.3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My method to show notification

That is not the code that is referenced in the stack trace. The stack trace shows that the `PendingIntent` is coming from Firebase Cloud Messaging.

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4'
```

Your version of Firebase Cloud Messaging is nearly five years old, a version that pre-dates Android 12. Please update your dependency to a newer version, such as `23.1.2`, and this particular source of this crash should go away.